Thread.join(1000) not waiting for worker to finish
why this code
public static void main(String [] argv){
        Logger l = LoggerFactory.getLogger( "MAIN" );

        Thread thread = new Thread(()->{
            Logger ll = LoggerFactory.getLogger( "WRKR" );
            ll.debug("start t1");
            try {
                Thread.sleep( 10000 );
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            }
            ll.debug("end t1");

        }) ;
        l.info("main");
        thread.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep( 8000 );
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }

        try {
            l.info("trying to join");
            thread.join(100);
            l.info("joined");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
        l.info("end main");
    }

produces this output:
10:57:38.871 [main] INFO MAIN - main
10:57:38.879 [Thread-0] DEBUG WRKR - start t1
10:57:46.884 [main] INFO MAIN - trying to join
10:57:46.993 [main] INFO MAIN - joined
10:57:46.993 [main] INFO MAIN - end main
10:57:48.880 [Thread-0] DEBUG WRKR - end t1

What's the point of join(100) not informing that the "worker" thread is still running?
I'd have expected a runtime exception.

"I'd have expected a runtime exception." Why? The documentation does only state two exceptions: "Throws: IllegalArgumentException - if the value of millis is negative
InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown." no timeout mentioned (the method terminated normally, no exception involved)

Your question is asking for opinions, and thus off-topic. The original implementers considered that if you want to wait for X milliseconds only, then you don't need to be informed and should check yourself. They have since decided differently with join(Duration). However, they can't change this for the existing methods, as that would be a breaking change, which they don't do.

The javadoc for join(long millis) method states "Waits at most millis milliseconds for this thread to terminate". It does not report the current state of the other thread so after your call thread.join(100); you don't have any information on the state of thread.
Since JDK19 you can use join with Duration which returns boolean which tells you whether the thread has terminated. If you view the source of join(Duration) it is equivalent to join(millis); with test isTerminated(); so you can call thread.isTerminated() if not currently using JDK19+.

Great to know! Anyway, I'm sadly still on Java 17

The Javadoc for t.join(duration) says, "Returns:...false if the thread has not terminated." That's a lie. A return value of false does not mean that the thread still is running. It only means that the join call timed out. We may presume that the thread was running at some moment before the join call timed out, but we have no way of knowing how long ago that moment was.

@SolomonSlow That is not a lie then. Of course it can't report on the state of the thread after the method returned...

@MarkRotteveel, The documentation is explicit. It says that a return value of false means that the thread has not terminated. What's the point of saying that a return value of X means Y if Y is not guaranteed to be true by the time the caller tests the value? A truthful description of the return value would say that false means that the call timed out, and the thread may or may not still be running at that point.

@SolomonSlow Yes, and that is exactly what it returns if you look at the code (I looked at the Java 21 code). The return value is the result of Thread.isTerminated(). In other words, at the time the method returns, it returns the termination state. It cannot predict the future, so if the thread terminates a nanosecond later, it obviously cannot report that.

If the return value does not predict the future, then the documentation is misleading at best. And, where it misleads is, it misleads junior developers into not thinking about how the state of some object may be changed by thread A after thread B has queried its state but before B can act on the information. That kind of misunderstanding, left unchecked, can lead to architectural flaws in real commercial software.

@SolomonSlow It cannot possibly predict the future: it only knows what the state was at the time it returned, and at that time it was either terminated or still running. Though your argument probably illustrates why the older join methods don't have a return value (though you'd probably then argue that querying Thread.isTerminated() also cannot predict the future, and thus is misleading...).
